# Meteor tutorials giving 'sanitizeForInObject' error

Tags: meteor

I have been using [Meteor](https://meteor.com) for years and have version 1.1 on my Mac. I have created a new directory, typed `meteor update` and checked that `meteor --version` gives Meteor 1.5.

Following the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app),  I typed `meteor create simple-todos`, `cd` into it, and typed `meteor`.

But meteor crashes - see the error below. How can I get the tutorial running? I'd still like to be able to run my older Meteor 1.1 app too.

`=> Started proxy.

=> Started MongoDB.

W20170605-21:34:04.700(10)? (STDERR) /Users/.../.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.3kmr7i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20170605-21:34:04.801(10)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20170605-21:34:04.801(10)? (STDERR)                        ^
W20170605-21:34:04.803(10)? (STDERR) 
W20170605-21:34:04.803(10)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitizeForInObject' of undefined
W20170605-21:34:04.804(10)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].LocalCollection.insert (packages/minimongo/minimongo.js:569:3)
W20170605-21:34:04.805(10)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].insert (packages/mongo/collection.js:524:37)
W20170605-21:34:04.805(10)? (STDERR)     at updateVersions (packages/autoupdate.js:133:20)
W20170605-21:34:04.806(10)? (STDERR)     at packages/autoupdate.js:197:3
W20170605-21:34:04.806(10)? (STDERR)     at Function.time (/Users/.../Javascript/meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)
W20170605-21:34:04.807(10)? (STDERR)     at /Users/.../Javascript/meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:347:13
W20170605-21:34:04.807(10)? (STDERR)     at /Users/.../Javascript/meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:388:5
W20170605-21:34:04.808(10)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/.../Javascript/meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20170605-21:34:04.809(10)? (STDERR)     at /Users/.../Javascript/meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:386:11
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.`

Comment: can you do a ```meteor reset``` and then try running again?

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error message after a `meteor reset`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to re-install Meteor as described on https://www.meteor.com/install, and then it all worked fine. I could even run Meteor version 1.1 in one directory and version 1.6 in another.